# ZF2 Email with german umlauts in from name

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-mail

I get the exception "Invalid header value detected", if I use german umlauts like 'äöü' in the from name of an email.

```
$message->setFrom('noreply@mydomain.de', 'äöü')
```

Does anyone know hot to fix this?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/oibhxa/zf2-set-utf-8-charset-in-e-mail-header

Comment: yes I have the some problem! I wasn't able to fix it, so I use a function that will replace the characters, if I am not mistaken, this issue is not related with zf2, but it is related with sendmail in linux, in fact if you echo the command, you will see that it fails at that level even when you set up the uft-8 option

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to convert the mail address to the correct writing (includes converted umlaut).

You can use icon php function for this action.